# Read bytes, convert to Integer

Tags: java, elf

The specification for an **ELF_64_word** states that variables of this type are four bytes in length and are *unsigned integers*.

```
Table 1. ELF-64 Data Types
Name         Size Alignment       Purpose
Elf64_Addr    8      8      Unsigned program address
Elf64_Off     8      8      Unsigned file offset
Elf64_Half    2      2      Unsigned medium integer
Elf64_Word    4      4      Unsigned integer
Elf64_Sword   4      4      Signed integer
Elf64_Xword   8      8      Unsigned long integer
Elf64_Sxword  8      8      Signed long integer
unsigned char 1      1      Unsigned small integer
```

I have a sequence of bytes where I have located four bytes of some Elf64_word. My question is how would I read these bytes as an unsigned integer in Java?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read them as an `int` (signed, 4 bytes), and at calculations convert it to a long:

```
int sint = ...

long uint = Integer.toUnsignedLong(sint);
```

Notice that [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) has many unsigned handling functions

- compareUnsigned(n, m)
- parseUnsignedInt - nice for hex
- toUnsignedString

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6891677/2243495) has some information about using a `ByteBuffer` to read `int`s from a binary file.

Comment: @andyg0808 thanks, and note that the ELF format specifies the endianess in a header byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat unsigned 64-bit integers as `long`s for most operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, left shifts).  Java gradually gets better unsigned integer support for the rest:

- [`Long.compareUnsigned(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-)  (although `==` and `!=` obviously work for (in)equality checks)
- [`Long.divideUnsigned(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#divideUnsigned-long-long-)
- [`Long.remainderUnsigned(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#remainderUnsigned-long-long-)
- [`Long.toUnsignedString(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString-long-) and [`Long.toUnsignedString(long, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toUnsignedString-long-int-)
- For right shifts (`>>`), make sure to use logical right shift (`>>>`).

Most 64-bit ELF values do not actually need 64 bits (because only very few 64-bit architectures support the full address range anyway), and where the format treats them as opaque, you do not have to perform any arithmetic on them, so `long` as a container is just fine.  In the cases where arithmetic is actually needed, you might even get away with using non-negative `int`s instead because if these quantities exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the resulting ELF binary would be several gigabytes large.

The most efficient way to parse bytes into `long`s is likely [`ByteBuffer.getLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getLong--) or one of its variants.